# What is the difference between “document.write(‘hello world\n’);” and “document.writeln(‘hello world’);”?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `document.write(‘hello world\n’);` and `document.writeln(‘hello world’);`?

**Edit**

My question is what will be the difference of output.

Comment: you need to use " in document.write("hello world\n") to echo the new line.

Comment: @thomasmalt: not in JavaScript you don't. Are you thinking of PHP or Ruby maybe?

Comment: gear-solid - I know you do a lot of front end work. I am tracking down front end bugs and documenting all of them. Can you contact me by AIM or email and report bugs directly to me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Historically, `writeln` was intended to handle different newline conventions, of with `\n` is only one.

There are different conventions for end-of-line. `'\n'` is the end-of-line marker on UNIX, `'\r'` on Mac (AFAIK not any more as it's now a UNIX) and `'\r\n'` is DOS/Windows. Using `writeln` should automatically use the correct one on the desired platform *in other languages*, but I don't really know whether JavaScript's `document.writeln` automatically uses the correct one automagically.

Comment: In MS domWeb.js, both `write` and `writeln` have the same implementation, nothing related to newlines.
`Document.write = function(content) { _setInnerHTML(this, content);
};
    Document.writeln = function(content) { _setInnerHTML(this, content);
};`

Answer (score 8):

> The writeln() method is identical to
>   the write() method, with the addition
>   of writing a newline character after
>   each statement.

from [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_writeln.asp)

**edit:** for the sake of completeness :)

[writeln on mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.writeln)

[writeln on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20001113/html.html#ID-35318390)

Comment: I think he knows that, what he asks is what is the difference with calling writeln with only the line to add vs. calling write and adding newline in the string using  `\n` at the end.

Comment: No downvote from me, but w3schools is very far from being any kind of authority on JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, writeln() appends a line feed to the end of your string.

In practice, since you're talking Javascript, there's little real difference if you're generating HTML, since HTML ignores extra white space anyway.

Comment: Read the question carefully: His `write` example also writes a line feed, using the `\n` character at the end of the string.

Comment: Spudley: not quite true: whitespace can be significant in HTML. For example, whitespace between two `<img>` elements will introduce a visible gap.

Comment: @Tim: yes, hence my use of the word *extra* (as in extra white space) and *little* (as in little real difference). There is, as you say a difference. But in practice, most use of document.write() or writeln() (in my experience) is to produce blocks of text rather than fully formed html, and in that context they probably won't see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

afaik there's no difference between them. You'll end up with a line, which has a "new-line-sign" at the end, so the next text youre gonna display will show up in the following line.

if this is a tricky question sorry for my ignorance:)

Answer (score 1):

document.write() writes to the document without appending a newline on the end.
document.writeln() writes to the document appending a newline at the end.

Comment: He knows that, what he asks is what is the difference with calling writeln with only the line to add vs. calling write and adding newline in the string using  `\n` at the end.

Comment: @awe But isn't the answer obvious? The benefit of using document.writeln() is that you don't need to write \n manually into your strings, and maybe that you don't need to think about platforms using \r\n as a line delimiter, but if the output is a webpage consumed by a browser that isn't an issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take this is as an example:

Out put for write():
Hello World!Have a nice day!

Note that write() does NOT add a new line after each statement.

Output for writeln():
Hello World!
Have a nice day!

Note that writeln() add a new line after each statement.

Answer (score 0):

**document.write** you will get the courser in the same line, but in **document.writeln** you will get the courser in the next line.